# changing code for supporting scripts in later generatet content

Tags: jquery

i try to use some function of bootstrap, input-tags for example.

If i include the bootstrap files and use the html-code, all is fine.

If i try to use that in a modal with a later generatet form, all these functions wont wore.

What i have to do, that the later generatet content can work with this scripts and functions, too?

Maybe there is another kind of incluing the scripts or i have to add additional code?

For a single function, i will now, that i have to change the functions with the ".on" element - but what i have to do for including hole scripts like bootstrap-scripts?

Comment: This is too broad. It depends entirely on the particular feature you want to use. For example, let's say you want to use bootstrap's tooltips so you load bootstrap and you call `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` and they work. Later, if you and new elements to the page, youll need to call `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` again to apply it to the new elements,  but if we're talking about event handlers, that's a different deal.

Comment: "$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();" this Code works for all kind of included JS Scripts? "tooltip" is in this examle the name of the function or another think?